# name of ros message

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I write a script to listen from a robot laser. I know which topic it is, but I cannot find the message name. So, I cannot use  its attribute like ranges[].
Could u please tell me how to deal with it, I am a beginner to ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149416/name-of-ros-message/) by [flightgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/14446/flightgong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suppose you are working in python, so I suggest you to look at this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29).
You can see the message type of a topic using the command `rostopic info /topic_name`, in your case the message type should be sensor_msgs/LaserScan.

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2014-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [flightgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/14446/flightgong/) on 2014-04-06**:
Hi,
I already know my topic name, but I use my script to listen the robot. SO, I need the laserscan data. However,   I have no idea how to extract the laser scan data.
thx!

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-04-06**:
maybe I didn't understood the question, but is the message type what you need? As I said use the command `rostopic info /topic_name`, where /topic_name is the name of your laser topic (should be sensor_msgs/LaserScan) then in your code (look at the tutorial) use `from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan` to import what you need.

**Comment by [flightgong](https://answers.ros.org/users/14446/flightgong/) on 2014-04-06**:
Thanks, actually I want to extract the laser scan data from the stageros robot. But I don't know how to do it?  Again, thx

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-04-07**:
Again, look at the tutorial I linked in my answer. This assumes obviously that you have done the previous tutorials and that you have programming knowledge in python (or C++).